# is there a way to put placeholders in excel files using phpspreadsheet?

Tags: php, phpexcel, phpspreadsheet, phpoffice-phpspreadsheet

is there any way to get placeholders in my excel file using phpspreadsheet? all I see I can do is using a specific cell to put my data into it
eg. setCellValue('A1','John')
I want to insert data into my excel where I have a placeholder not into a specific cell, looking for something similar to phpword
eg. setValue($placeholder,'John')

I've been looking for a solution for quite a while now but I can't find any function to help me out.

Answer (score 1):

You can try it.

```
    $spreadSheet = new \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet;
    $placeholder = 'D'
    $i = 5;
    $spreadSheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue($placeholder . $i, 'John');
```

Comment: thanks for answering figured it out on my own after i saw ur reply lol
`foreach ($sheet->getRowIterator() as $row) {
    $cellIterator = $row->getCellIterator();   
    $cellIterator->setIterateOnlyExistingCells(TRUE);
    if($cellName == ""){
        foreach ($cellIterator as $cell) {        
            $value = $cell->getValue();         
            if($value == "John"){    
                $cellName = $cell->getCoordinate();            
        }
    }else {
        break;
    }        
}`